# AudioTrack to specific device via AudioFlinger

Tags: android, c++, systems-programming

I'm doing some system programming on Android.

I have AudioTrack object and need to specify on which device it should be played. How I can do that?

In system/audio.h there is audio_device_t which can specify cases and flags of possible audio outputs, but I cannot set that in my AudioTrack.

Is there way to specify on which device track would go?

Thanks,